# Android TV Registration in Google Cast SDK Developer Console

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast, android-tv

I am planning to add Google cast feature on my existing iOS and Android application streaming audio application.

I don't have Chrome cast device. But i have Android TV(KDL-43W950C).

Can i use my Android TV for developing Google-cast application?
If it so, how to register Android TV in Google Cast Developer Console?. Android TV has the serial number of 7 digits, where as registration form expects 8-20 characters.

Google Chrome cast application also does not detect the Android TV

Google Document covers for the Chrome cast devices, not for Android TV.

Answer (score 1):

This [page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration#RegisterDevice) has information about registering Android TV:

> For an Android TV device you can also get the serial number on Android
>   TV: from the Settings menu, select About and scroll down to see the
>   Serial Number.

You can then enter the serial number in the developer console. See that page for details.

Comment: I did follow the instruction. Setting->About screen does not display the Serial number. I got the serial number from Help->Show System Information. But Serial number is 7 Digit, But Developer console is expecting 8-20 characters.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. i have resolved the issue by using Device ID. i updated the same in the Answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ***Device ID*** should be used(Not the Serial Number). Using the Device ID i am able to register and cast the sample program in to Android TV.

Google Cast Developer console does not accept the serial number, as it has only 7 digits.