# While using Google Cast to cast to Android TV, is it possible to capture the remote control buttons of the Android TV?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, android-tv, google-cast-sdk

I have a CAF receiver and would like to utilize some of the Android TV buttons on it. Is it possible?

Also, I can't get to the debug console of the CAF receiver when using Android TV. I have an ADT-2, what serial number should I be entering on the Google Cast Developer Console?

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. If you go to https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview and cast to the device(You can see cast option on Chrome browser), you can get the serial number, it will show the serial number on the tv.

Comment: 2- That is a really cool trick, thank you. Unfortunately even though I did have the right serial, it still won't let me debug it. Works fine for all my other chromecasts.

Answer (score 0):

On the second question regarding registration of an Android TV device, there was a similar question asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591350/android-tv-registration-in-google-cast-sdk-developer-console) (although not ADT-2 specific, but I suppose it applies to ADT-2 too).

I fail to cast my custom receiver app to an Android TV device though. Having registered the serial number in Google cast developer console, I get a `session_error` without details when trying to setup a cast session. On a second generation chromecast dongle, or a chromecast ultra, it works fine.

Comment: Might be the same issue. Doesn't happen to me because I'm testing a public receiver but since it doesn't show the debug options then I bet it wouldn't work with unpublished receivers.